# $X\subseteq Y$ looking for $f:Y\rightarrow Y$ 1-1 and onto such that $f(x)=x \iff x\in X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X,Y two infinite sets such that:

- $X\subseteq Y$
- $|Y\setminus X|\geq_c 2$ (the set difference has cardinality greater than 2)

I’m trying to prove that there exists a one-to-one and onto function 
$f:Y \rightarrow Y$ such that

**$f(x)=x\iff  x\in X$.**

I managed to find such a function when $|Y\setminus X|\leq_c |\mathbb{N}|$ but failed when $|Y\setminus X|>_c |\mathbb{N}|$.

Any suggestions?

**Thank you in advance for your time and effort.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** If $Y\setminus X$ is infinite then it can be written as a union of pairs.

(Of course, this requires the axiom of choice, otherwise it is consistent that there is a counterexample.)

Comment: So we ‘ll define a Relation $R\subseteq(Y\setminus X)x(Y\setminus X)$ as follows: $xRy \iff x\neq y$. Then by A.C. there exists a function $f: (Y\setminus X) \rightarrow (Y\setminus X)$ such that $f(x)=y$ and then expand the identical function $id:X\rightarrow X$?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I’m given the following definition of the A.C.

For every relation $R\subseteq AxB$. If $(\forall x\in A)(\exists y\in B)[xRy]$ Then $ (\exists f:A\rightarrow B)[(\forall x\in A)[xRf(x)]]$. 

So by defining a relation R in $(Y \setminus X)\times (Y\setminus X)$ such that $xRy \iff x\neq y$ I can then assume the existence of a function from  $Y\setminus X$ to $Y\setminus X$ such that $xRf(x)$?

Comment: But how do you know this function is injective or surjective? The hint is not to use the axiom of choice, it's to use its consequences.

Comment: Could this be so simple?

According to your hint: When $Y\setminus X$ is infinite it can be written as follows $ Y\setminus X=\cup_{i\in I}\{a_i,b_i\},a_i\neq b_i$. Define $g: Y\setminus X  \rightarrow Y\setminus X $ such that $g(a_i)=b_i$ and $g(b_i)=a_i$. If $id:X\rightarrow X $ then $f=g\cup id$?

Comment: Yes. That would be it.